# how to set layout background transparent show popup window in android?

Tags: android, layout, popupwindow

I would like to be able to either blur or dim the layout background when I show my popup window Like this.how do this pls help me.

This my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ResidentActivity.this
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View layout = inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.activity_appselection,
                            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popuplayoutelement));
                    pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 470, 540, true);
                    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 45);
```

my output show this

[image]
but i need like this
[image]

Comment: Have you tried at least to search on Stackoverflow or on Google?

Comment: refere: http://www.thaicreate.com/mobile/android-seekbar-alertdialog-popup.html

Comment: try alpha property which sets transparency where value ranges from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare the main parent in your layout like this for example:

`RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);`

Then when you show your popup also add this statement.

`rl.setAlpha(0.5F);`

This will set alpha to 50% in the layout. You can tweak as necessary.

Comment: oh yeah - my tablet makes much better use of its area now!